# Error en la consulta de base de datos al evitar una inyeccion sql php

Tags: php, inyección-sql

Estoy intentando evitar la inyección SQL. El problema lo tengo a la hora de ejecutar el query.

Al darle al botón de "buscar" del formulario, entra en la condicional `if ($ok = "false")` y muestra como mensaje `"Error al ejecutar la consulta"`.

Ya verifiqué los campos de la base de datos y al parecer todo está bien y debería saltarse esa condición y entrar en el `else`.

Aquí les dejo los campos de la base de datos:

```
CODART, SECCION, NOMBREARTICULO, PRECIO, FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAISDEORIGEN
```

Y aquí les dejo mi código:

```
<?php 
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_nombre = "db_prueba"; 
$db_usuario = "root"; 
$db_pass = ""; 

$busqueda = $_GET["buscar"]; 

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_pass) or die ("No se pudo conectar" . mysqli_error($conexion)); 
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos");
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); 

$query = "SELECT CODART, SECCION, PRECIO, PAISDEORIGEN FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PAISDEORIGEN = ?"; 
$result = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query); 
$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "s", $busqueda); 
$ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($result); 

if ($ok == "false"){ 
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta";
} else { 
    $ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $codart, $seccion, $precio, $pais);
    echo "<h2>Articulos encontrados: </h2>"; 

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)){
        echo $codart. " ". $seccion. " ". $precio. " ". $pais. "<br>";
    } 
    mysqli_stmt_close($result); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli-stmt.execute](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) **retorna un valor booleano** `1 ó 0` ,cambiar su `if`

```
if ($ok){ 
   $ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $codart, $seccion, $precio, $pais);
   /* Demás líneas */
  }
  else
  {  
  echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta";  
  }
}
```